# Gradle problem when add new places SDK from google

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have this problem when I add the new Places SDK for Android.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

Im using this URL: **https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration**

*This is my gradle:*

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    api('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') {
        transitive = false
    }
    api('com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.6.3') {
        exclude module: 'android-beacon-library' //remove to use Proximity messaging
        exclude module: 'play-services-location' //remove to use Geofence or Proximity messaging
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    api 'com.commonsware.cwac:sacklist:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    api 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
    api 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    api 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.0.0'
    api 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:1.0.0'
    api 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    api 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
    api 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'
    api 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    api 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    api 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.12.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

I have this problem:

```
error: cannot access zzbfm
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found
```

Comment: Update your firebase and gms dependencies to 16.x.x